# system files application

Tags: system

How to open/access app file folder such as; device;sdcard;emulater0; sdcard emulater; and what do they mean?  when i try to open them it says "doesn't have app to view" What is a good app to get to view them? do i need to do it on a computer? Also  Facefile says no media with a bunch of letters  What is this?; How to view Thumbnailsin the file folder?  thank you in advance for any help with this. i have a samsung Galaxy s3

Answer (score 1):

I would try ES File Explorer. It's a really useful manager and could probably open it.

If not, you can use Root Explorer. Yes, you will need root, and yes, it costs, money. But if you change your system files a lot it's a really great tool. Plus, you have a 2 hour trial period after you purchase, so if it doesn't work you can get a refund.

Answer (score 0):

First off you need to root your device and after that you can download root explorer(paid) to acess that file

You can download via torrent if you don't wanna pay for the app

For root you can check xda developers